# Concerns with asynchronous opening of JDialog with owner frame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have read that all of Java swing is not thread safe.

I am loading data from a remote site asynchronously and displaying it in a dialog once it has loaded. My concern is that if swing is not thread-safe as it claims, I'm afraid that I will cause an issue when I set the dialog's owner frame, which is in a different thread.

If I am correct in my concern, what can I do to open the dialog synchronously and avoid any issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing component must be created and updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

When you load data using a separate Thread you can then use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to create the dialog and its components.

Or another option is to use a `SwingWorker`. When the background processing of the worker is finished your code can then automatically be executed on the EDT.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and working examples.